# Segment Bar loaded event gets called on activityResumedEvent

Tags: android, nativescript

In my NativeScript app on android, I am using one segment bar and I have noticed that (loaded) event gets called every time user minimise the app and resumes it again.

```
<SegmentedBar width="100%" height="100%" selectedIndex="{{segmentedIndex}}" (selectedIndexChange)="onSelectedIndexChange($event)"
                    style="font-family: 'FontAwesome'" (loaded)="onBarLoaded($event)">
                    <SegmentedBarItem title="{{currentText | decodeHTML}}" class="fa label-text-icon"></SegmentedBarItem>
                    <SegmentedBarItem title="{{pastText | decodeHTML}}" class="fa label-text-icon"></SegmentedBarItem>
                </SegmentedBar>
            </StackLayout>
```

is this the expected behaviour or is it a bug?
P.S. I am making an API call on bar loaded and every time activity resume, app makes API call again. If that is th expected behaviour then I may need to  handle the event

```
android.on(AndroidApplication.activityResumedEvent, function (args: AndroidActivityEventData) {

        console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a bug but an expected behaviour. Loaded events will be called whenever the native view is recycled, like resume / navigating back to previous page. I think using application settings here may be an overhead. Why don't you try removing your listener after first use?

```
export function onLoaded(args) {
    // Removes any loaded event listeners attached in the object
    args.object.off('loaded');
    // Write code here
}
```

**Update:** The above solution might be a good fit for Core application, for Angular we can use a directive that will listen to given event only once.

**listen-once.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { View } from "ui/core/view";

@Directive({
    selector: "[listenOnce]",
})
export class ListenOnceDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input() eventName: string = View.loadedEvent;
    @Output() listenOnce: EventEmitter<EventData> = new EventEmitter();

    listener: () => void;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.listener = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, this.eventName, (event: EventData) => {
            this.removeListener();
            this.listenOnce.emit(event);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.removeListener();
    }

    private removeListener() {
        if (this.listener) {
            this.listener();
            this.listener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you import this directive in appropriate module. Then you can simply do this on segmented bar

```
<SegmentedBar width="100%" height="100%" selectedIndex="{{segmentedIndex}}" (selectedIndexChange)="onSelectedIndexChange($event)"
                style="font-family: 'FontAwesome'" (listenOnce)="onBarLoaded($event)">
                <SegmentedBarItem title="{{currentText | decodeHTML}}" class="fa label-text-icon"></SegmentedBarItem>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="{{pastText | decodeHTML}}" class="fa label-text-icon"></SegmentedBarItem>
            </SegmentedBar>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I have this for segment bar (loaded)="onBarLoaded($event)". Do you mean remove the listener onBarLoaded function?

Comment: That's bit complicated with Angular, I use a directive that will add listeners only once to the element. Let me share that in the answer.

Comment: thank for your edit, meanwhile I have tested the original solution args.object.off('loaded'); and that is also working fine.

Comment: Yes, that could work. But I would recommend sticking to framework features and best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I passed that bug using a flag var to identify already load that view, for example when load I save a var called loaded = 1 then at the top of loaded event check if that was loaded

```
var applicationSettings = require("application-settings");
var isloated = applicationSettings.getString("loaded",0);
if(isolated == 0){
   here means that is the first time
}else{
   do nothing
}
```

Comment: Yup, for the workaround sake I am also doing the same and instead of saving in localstorage, I am using a boolean. But interested to know if this is a real bug?